# Проблема с padding-bottom у iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

Подскажите, кто сталкивался.
Нужно видео с youtube вместить в определенные рамки. Но для того, чтобы вписать видео в этот блок, вынужден был поставить padding-bottom: 36%. И теперь нет возможности нижний блок (в голубой рамке на скрине) прижать к нижней границе блока, который над ним. [image: Проблема с padding-bottom]

Если уменьшать padding-bottom, блок приближается к своему месту, но высота видео уменьшается. Вот часть css.

```
.calendar__general-slyde-video {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 36%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 315px;
}
.calendar__general-slyde-video iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60%;
}
```

Буду благодарен, кто подскажет как быть!

Comment: А почему нельзя просто все завернуть в один див и отталкиваться от этого блока с календарем?

Comment: Напиши конкретнее, весь код, твоих слов недостаточно, надо видеть:

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mz7vti

Comment: необходимо использовать margin-bottom

Answer (score 0):

`.calendar__general-slyde-video iframe` у вас имеет высоту, заданную в %. Если у этого элемента не существует контейнеров (парент элементов), имеющих явно заданную высоту, то % в конечном итоге может оказаться равным чему угодно. Так и получается - паддинг в 36% приводит к увеличению общей высоты парент-контейнера, от которой пляшет и высота видео.

Comment: Подскажите пож-ста, как мне тогда быть в моем случае? Задать конкретную высоту в px? Попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: задайте конкретную высоту контейнеру